# why does the number of bytes of an image changes when I use UIImageJPEGRepresentation method?

Tags: cocoa

I am trying to send an image file from client(Mac) to server(UNIX) using sockets. I am using a image file which is 10.2 KB size and having a 16 KB size on disk. When i am converting this image into NSData and sequentially into bytes, using the method UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0), the no of bytes that are being transferred to the server is around 55 KB. At the same time, if i am using 0.95 as the compressionQuality, the size drops to 22 KB.
The funniest part is, for a smaller image of around 3400 bytes (4 KB on disk), the image is getting transferred only when i give the compressionQuality as 1.0 (sending 9300 bytes)and not getting transferred when giving 0.75 and this is exactly opposite case with the larger file which gets transferred at 0.75 and not at 1.0

Any help is appreciated and Thanks in advance

I have been using UIImageJPEGRepresentation for converting the image into NSData and intern getting bytes from that image and sending it through socket. Is this not the right way to send an Image file? If not, kindly guide me in the right path.

Comment: If you are sending a file what has UIImageJPEGRepresentation got to do with it? Secondly, you sound surprised that different compression settings result in different amounts of compressed data? That's what the compression setting is for. Thirdly, you have a bug in your code, you must show your code if you want anyone to help.

Comment: I have been using UIImageJPEGRepresentation for converting the image into NSData and intern getting bytes from that image and sending it through socket. Is this not the right way to send an Image file? If not, kindly guide me in the right path.

Comment: well it depends, if you have an image file (which is what the wording of your question suggests) you would do [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"path/to/file.jpg")

Comment: I am picking the image from the saved photo albums in the iPhone simulator. I don't have the path of the file, but i have the image which made me to use the method UIImageJPEGRepresentation. Is there a way to get the path of that particular image what I have picked from the photo album dynamically from the simulator?